# Pass ViewBag data to requirejs or knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, requirejs, viewbag

I'm new to js and now trying to integrate [HTML5 AJAX File Uploader Module](https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader) into my ASP.NET MVC project.

In my project, there's a `ViewBag.UserID`, and in the view I use the script from the module:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/scripts/main" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

I suppose I can pass `UserID` to `main.js` using the script above, so that I can use something like

```
var UserID;

html5Upload.initialize({
    // URL that handles uploaded files
    uploadUrl: '/file/upload?Userid=' + UserID,

    ...
    });
```

But... how can I do to fulfill that?

Comment: it seems there will be only single value in UserId,so you can use Session instead of viewbag.

Comment: You need a parameter to your JS function, then just pass the UserID to the JS function from your View. You dont really need something like Knockout for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have some bootstrapping code to integrate server-side globals into your javascript. E.g.:

```
<script>
(function(myNamespace) {
  "use strict";

  myNamespace.UserInfo = {
    UserID: '@ViewBag.UserID' // injects viewbag info into javascript
  };

}(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {}));
</script>
```

Now any bit of javascript you have can access the global `myNamespace` variable's `UserInfo` property, which contains the viewbag data. For example:

```
uploadUrl: '/file/upload?Userid=' + myNamespace.UserInfo.UserID,
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jeroen's suggestion is quite correct. However, here's another approach which might be overkill for your purposes, but you could also use it in many other places: [SuperScript](http://supertext.github.io/SuperScript.JavaScript/index.html#!/index) is a library which allows you to declare, for example, a JavaScript variable in server-side code and have that variable *emitted* to the output webpage however you like.

So in your case you could have something like

```
SuperScript.JavaScript.Declarations.AddVariable(opt => opt.EmitterKey("javascript")
                                                          .Name("user_id")
                                                          .Value(UserID));
```

And on your Razor view / _layout

```
@SuperScript.Declarations.EmitFor("javascript")
```

Which would write out

```
var user_id = "...";    // the string value of UserID
```

Aside from the extensibility behind this solution, it allows you to avoid errors in shared views where ViewBag properties aren't present, and offers a way to easily move values/objects from code to front-end.

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the developers of SuperScript.